# How to find form element by it's name

Tags: jquery, forms, attributes

I'm trying to find the form element type (i.e. textarea, input etc.) by only having its 'name' attribute. Is there any way of achieving this with jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get the element by its name attribute](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector#):

```
$('[name="someName"]')
```

Then [get the first element with `[0]`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
$('[name="someName"]')[0]
```

Then get the tag name with [`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeName) and normalise it with [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase):

```
$('[name="someName"]')[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()
```

---

In jQuery 1.6, you can do this slightly more beautifully (if a little more slowly) by using [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop):

```
$('[name="someName"]').prop('nodeName');
```

I don't *think* this will be normalised, so you'll need to do so yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$(":input[name='your_name']")
```

`:input` returns all input form elements (textara, radios, texts, selects, etc)

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='yourname']")

$("textarea[name='yourname_textarea']")
```

Comment: Sorry, but if I knew what the element type is I wouldn't be looking for it